# MySQL IF version < x THEN ELSE

Tags: mysql

How would I write an `IF` ... `THEN` ... `ELSE` within MySQL where my IF is testing for the server version number? Pointers to the correct section of the docs are appreciated. More details are really appreciated.

**Update:**

*Apologies for an unintentionally vague question.*

*I keep a sql script ready to create databases and users easily when I deploy something on machines (new to me). Different servers are running different versions of the software and I wanted to make the script reliable and version-aware.*

Comment: With your coding pencil?

Comment: What do you mean by this? What versions are you working with and what problem are you trying to solve? Baking this into a query is a super bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer this because you haven't described what you're trying to do, but you may like to know about a neat feature of MySQL SQL comment syntax to make some parts of a query version-dependent.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

> If you add a version number after the “!” character, the syntax within
>   the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is greater than or
>   equal to the specified version number. The TEMPORARY keyword in the
>   following comment is executed only by servers from MySQL 3.23.02 or
>   higher:
>
> CREATE /*!32302 TEMPORARY */ TABLE t (a INT);

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [version](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version) global variable.

```
mysql> select @@VERSION;
+-----------------+
| @@VERSION       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.26-74.0-log |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use the VERSION() function or @@VERSION variable to get the current
  mysql version.
- Use the [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)( condition , value_if_true, value_if_false)
  function to make a basic testing.
- Use a combination of [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) like SUBSTRING,
  VERSION, and LOCATE to extract some part of the version string.

Ej: (mayor version number, from `'5.6.26-74.0-log'` extracts `'5'`)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( @@VERSION , 1 , LOCATE( '.' , @@VERSION ) )
```